# How to pass Environment Variables to Helmfile Values file

Tags: azure-devops, go-templates, helmfile

I am new to `helmfile` and I want to use an exported environment variable that I use in the helmfile values file when running the helmfile diff.

I have the following `helmfile.yaml` as below:

```
repositories:
  - name: backstage
    url: https://backstage.github.io/charts
  # - name: backstage-additional-configs
  #   url: ./backstage-additional-configs

helmDefaults:
  cleanupOnFail: true
  verify: false
  wait: true
  timeout: 180
  historyMax: 0
  recreatePods: true
  atomic: true
  createNamespace: false

helmfiles:
  - path: releases/releases.yaml
    values:
      - {{ .Environment.Name }}.yaml

environments:
  dev:
    values:
      - dev.yaml.gotmpl
```

And here's how my `dev.yaml.gotmpl` looks like

```
backstage:
  image:
    registry: somregistry
    image: someimage
    tag: {{ .Values.IMAGE_TAG | quote }}
```

And I am using the Azure DevOps pipelines to execute `helmfile` commands because I need to dynamically set the `IMAGE_TAG` value based on the `$(Build.BuildId)`, so here's my `pipeline.yaml` look like:

```
. . .

    - task: AzureCLI@1
        displayName: 'Run helmfile - diff'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.keyvault_service_connection }}
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript' # Options: inlineScript, scriptPath
          inlineScript: |
            set -euo pipefail
            export IMAGE_TAG=$(Build.BuildId)  #<-------- exporting here
            helmfile -b /usr/local/bin/helm3 -e ${{ parameters.env }} repos
            helmfile -b /usr/local/bin/helm3 -e ${{ parameters.env }} diff
```

So I am exporting the `IMAGE_TAG` with `export IMAGE_TAG=$(Build.BuildId)` command.

I get the following error:

> in ./helmfile.yaml: failed to read helmfile.yaml: failed to load environment values file "dev.yaml.gotmpl": failed to render [dev.yaml.gotmpl], because of template: stringTemplate:18:19: executing "stringTemplate" at <.Values.IMAGE_TAG>: map has no entry for key "IMAGE_TAG"

I also tried `tag: "{{ .Values.IMAGE_TAG }}"`

Could someone please help me what am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try `export IMAGE_TAG=$BUILD_BUILDID`? Mixing pipeline macro syntax `$()` with inline scripts can be dangerous and error-prone; system variables like `Build.BuildId` are already created automatically as environment variables, so you can access them using standard environment variable syntax.

Comment: Hi @DanielMann, I have exported as in my question above `export IMAGE_TAG=$(Build.BuildId)`. My other doubt is, `tag: {{ .Values.IMAGE_TAG | quote }}` is this the right way of accessing the environment variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values from the environment aren't normally visible in Helmfile templating (or in plain Helm).

Helmfile includes `env` and `requiredEnv` template functions and [the documentation includes an example of using them](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#using-environment-variables).  In your `*.yaml.gotmpl` file you need to explicitly request the environment value; it won't be automatically reflected in the Helmfile values.

```yaml
# dev.yaml.gotmpl
tag: {{ requiredEnv "IMAGE_TAG" | quote }}
```

[`env`](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templating_funcs/#env) defaults to an empty string if the environment variable isn't set, the same way as saying `"$IMAGE_TAG"` in a shell; you can combine it with `default`.  [`requiredEnv`](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templating_funcs/#requiredenv) produces a fatal error if the variable isn't set.

In principle you can use the `helmfile --state-values-set` option to inject this value to the Helmfile-level values, so that the template syntax you show in the question works.  This isn't heavily documented, though.  Its syntax is presumably similar to `helm --set`, which comes with some unusual syntax and some things it can and can't directly set; for a simple string value it would be a reasonable alternative here.

The Helmfile terminology is a little bit confusing here because Helmfile also has a notion of [environments](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#environment), often things like "dev" vs. "prod", which is different from the Unix (shell) environment.

Comment: Hi @David, thank you for you answer. It is working properly. If I want to pass multiple values, should I use `--state-values-set` multiple times? eg: `helmfile -e dev --state-values-set IMAGE_TAG=$IMAGE_TAG --state-values-set SOME_VALUE=somevalue`

Comment: It appears so; [the option has an array value in the code](https://github.com/helmfile/helmfile/blob/v0.159.0/cmd/root.go#L121).

Comment: Thank you :), I also have another issue I am trying to fix, could you also look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77708839/how-to-pass-arguments-in-azure-devops-pipeline if you have time?

Comment: No need to use it multiple times. Just separate the values with commas, as documented in the source line linked before. key1=val1,key2=val2