# How to pass "arguments" in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have this Azure DevOps pipeline that is using `AzureCLI@1` task as below.

```
- task: AzureCLI@1
  displayName: 'Run helmfile - diff'       
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.keyvault_service_connection }}
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript' # Options: inlineScript, scriptPath
    arguments:
      -RESOURCEGRP 'TEST-RG'
    inlineScript: |
      set -euo pipefail
      set -x
      SERVICEHELM=$(mktemp)
      $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/pipeline-templates/build/bin/resolve_keyvaults_in_helm.sh ${{ parameters.keyvault_name }} ${{ parameters.env }}.yaml > $SERVICEHELM
      cp $SERVICEHELM ${{ parameters.env }}.yaml
      rm -f $SERVICEHELM
      echo $RESOURCEGRP
      helmfile -b /usr/local/bin/helm3 -e ${{ parameters.env }} repos
      # helmfile -b /usr/local/bin/helm3 -e ${{ parameters.env }} diff
     
    workingDirectory: ${{ parameters.environment_directory }}
```

But when I try to run the pipeline, I get the following error message

> RESOURCEGRP: unbound variable

Could someone please help me with this?

Thank You!

Comment: The double dash (--) is used to specify named arguments in Azure CLI. Try using --RESOURCEGRP 'TEST-RG'

Comment: Hi @Daqs, I was just wondering if this works when `scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'` ?

Comment: Because I still get the same issue

Answer (score 0):

To Pass `arguments` in DevOps `Azure CLI task`, you should use `$1`, `$2` in the script content. You can also find the sample in official doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines#examples).

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@1
  displayName: 'Run helmfile - diff'       
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMConn3'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript' # Options: inlineScript, scriptPath
    arguments: 'Test-RG1 Test-RG2'
    inlineScript: |
      set -euo pipefail
      set -x
      echo "The argument you passed is: $1 $2"
```

[image]

> RESOURCEGRP: unbound variable

The error you encountered is NOT caused by the argument, but caused by the `$RESOURCEGRP` value doesn't exist in the environment(when you use `set -euo pipefail` ahead).

I can reproduce the same error with below simple code:

[image]

The error will be fixed if you have set `$RESOURCEGRP` ahead in environment, eg: add `variable` ahead or `export RESOURCEGRP=....` in script.

[image]

> I want to pass this environment variable from another pipeline.

To pass environment variable from another pipeline, you should NOT work on the current pipeline, you could have options below:

1. If two pipelines has some relationships, like pipeline A(source) trigger pipeline B(target), you can **pass variable from source pipeline to target one**. You can find the sample script from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77617718/14996050).
2. You can also use same [Variable Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/variable-group/variable?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-variable-group-variable-update) between two pipelines. On source pipeline, you can update the variables value in the group, so that the target pipeline can get the value for execution.

To update the variable in source pipeline:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your valuable time answering this. I will try this out :)

Comment: Hi @JananathBanuka, may i know if there's any update? let me know if you have any queries.